# How to set profile avatar with uploaded photo in buddypress?

Tags: buddypress

How can I set the user's profile photo by the one of photos uploaded?

I use `get_avatar()` to get the currently set avatar.

Thanks

Comment: Surely if `get_avatar` gets it, `set_avatar` sets it? Otherwise, post your code showing what you have tried and explain why it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress also provide the plugins for it to change avatar.

Check the below link

[change avatar](http://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/add-new-default-avatar.1.3.1.zip)

To change the default avatar you can also try this

```
define ( 'BP_AVATAR_DEFAULT', $img_url );
define ( 'BP_AVATAR_DEFAULT_THUMB', $img_url );
```